# GCP Service account billing related

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-billing

I am planning to establish my web application to GCP(server to server) communication using the service account, so I create a service account and ask my customer to grant the service account with appropriate access to their Cloud data via IAM Policies. I would like to know who will be billed if I make an API request to fetch customer projects/resources?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, please. You are using a service account in your customer's project to access Cloud APIs? Generally if you use a resource in project A it will be paid by project A, but I'm not sure I understand your use case.

Comment: For accessing customer's resources in a project thru API, I will be creating a service account in my gcp project and ask the customer to add the service account as a IAM user and Grant role to the service account. Now using the private key of the service account, I will be able to fetch customer's resources defined in his project. The question is, when the API calls are made to fetch customer's resources, will I be billed or the customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading Google's ["Understanding Service Accounts"](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts), We learn that a service account can be either an *identity* or a *resource*.

I think in your case it's the first:

So the customer, by adding permissions in IAM for your service account just like for an end-user, agrees for you to take actions on his project resources that will be billed to the billing account connected to his project.

On the other hand, using Service Accounts as resources means you will give other users permission to use your project and take actions that will be billed to the account configured in your GCP project.

Answer (score 0):

In the service account json file will be the key `project_id`. This will be the project billed for activity using that service account.

Open the service account json file in an editor. The start of the file will look like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "development-123456",
```

Project `development-123456` will be billed.